# material-kit-react.scss?v=1.8.0 not working on mac anymore

Tags: node.js, sass, material-design, node-sass

All over sudden I can not build my website created with Creative Tim any more due to issues with sass and node:

```
material-kit-react.scss?v=1.8.0
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
```

There seam to be no working combination of them both. Tied every suggestions form GitHub but nothing has helped.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a solution by downgrading node to v12 with the nvm manager